# How to stack Text vertically with rotation using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to align text elements as shown in the image below:

[image]

How to do it in Jetpack Compose?

Normally I would use a Linear Layout with vertical orientation and TextViews with a `rotation of 90`. Wondering how to achieve this in compose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show vertical text with proper size/layout in jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057396/how-to-show-vertical-text-with-proper-size-layout-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*compose_verion: `1.0.0-beta02`*

To rotate an element you can use `Modifier.rotate()` modifier

```kotlin
Column {
     Text(text = "text", modifier = Modifier.rotate(-90f))
     Text(text = "text", modifier = Modifier.rotate(-90f))
     Text(text = "text", modifier = Modifier.rotate(-90f))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find a way to have a "wrap_content" after rotation but I hope it helps:

```
Column (...) {
    Text("Element 1",
        style = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
        modifier = Modifier
        .drawBackground(color = Color.Red)
        .padding(16.dp)
        .size(20.dp, 100.dp)
        .drawLayer(
            rotationZ = -90f
        )
        .size(100.dp, 20.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: It did work thanks! It is a pointer to move forward. Wrap_content is what to figure out next on top of this solution.

Answer (score 3):

The solution with a custom modifier from [How to show vertical text with proper size/layout in jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057396/how-to-show-vertical-text-with-proper-size-layout-in-jetpack-compose) worked for me:

```kotlin
fun Modifier.vertical() = layout { measurable, constraints ->
    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
    layout(placeable.height, placeable.width) {
        placeable.place(
            x = -(placeable.width / 2 - placeable.height / 2),
            y = -(placeable.height / 2 - placeable.width / 2)
        )
    }
}
```

Used as

```kotlin
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.vertical().rotate(-90f),
    text = "Vertical aligned element"
)
```

Credits to [Sergei S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058688/3329810).

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of [Sergei S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058688/3329810) that combines the `rotate` and `vertical` modifiers into one, to make it easier to use

```
fun Modifier.rotateVertically(clockwise: Boolean = true): Modifier {
    val rotate = rotate(if (clockwise) 90f else -90f)
    
    val adjustBounds = layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
        layout(placeable.height, placeable.width) {
            placeable.place(
                x = -(placeable.width / 2 - placeable.height / 2),
                y = -(placeable.height / 2 - placeable.width / 2)
            )
        }
    }
    return rotate then adjustBounds
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Text(
    text = "I'm going to be rotated clockwise",
    modifier = Modifier.rotateVertically()
)
```