# how to rotate and place text so that some is rotated and some is not in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image: my current image]

I have this image already.

What I am trying for is more like

[image]

I am new to compose, I am not quite clear on how to do this, so this my fun; thanks!

```
 @Composable
 fun MyDate() {

 var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
 var month = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, 
 Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())
var day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString()

Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.rotate(90f),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            text = month
        )

    Text(text = day)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stack Text vertically with rotation using Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767755/how-to-stack-text-vertically-with-rotation-using-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap them in a row

```
    Row() {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.rotate(90f),
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        text = month
    )

    Text(text = day)
}
```